# Does "law" here refer to a scientific law?

Tags: meaning, literature

Does "law" here refer to a scientific law?

> The first outstanding incident was the mediumship of the Eddy
> brothers, which has probably never been excelled in the matter of
> materialization, or, as we may now call them, ectoplasmic forms. The
> difficulty at that date in accepting such phenomena lay in the fact that
> they seemed to be regulated **by no known law**, and to be isolated from
> all our experiences of Nature. The labours of Geley, Crawford, Madame
> Bisson, Schrenck Notzing and others have removed this, and have given
> us, what is at the lowest, a complete scientific hypothesis, sustained by
> prolonged and careful investigations, so that we can bring some order
> into the matter.

*[The History of Spiritualism](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap12)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XII: THE EDDY BROTHERS AND THE HOLMESES</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the rules that govern the limits of what is possible within the realms of current scientific understanding.